# Passing only selected row datagridview to a new form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a large number of data in my datagridview**1**, but what I want now, is to pass only the selected row into a new form's datagridview**2**, so far I had only found out about this line of code. Will it be of any help?

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
//pass selected row's from datagridview1(form1) to datagridview(form2)
             }
```

Can anyone help me out on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the newform in form 1 like this :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
```

Declare newform's datagridview modifier as public, then add the following in your code :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {

                ((Form2)f).dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Try this , if you found any error, notify me...

Comment: so i declared System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["newform"]; in form1, 

and form2,

   public void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {

                ((newform)f).dataGridView2.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }

(newform)f) couldn't work, namespace could not be found.

Comment: change the name of newform to your form2 , System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form2"];

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by setting a public property in form2 like

`public List<DataGridViewRow> Form1_SelectedRowsList`

So that you can do object forwarding like

`form2 frm = new form2 { Form1_SelectedRowsList = dataGridView1.SelectedRows }`

In the form2_FormLoad event you can do

`dataGridView2.DataSource = Form1_SelectedRowsList`